# Moving projects from Jira Cloud based server to local server

Tags: server, migration, jira

We read a lot about issues when moving from one Jira server instance to another. Is it really that difficult and any risks regarding it?

What i want to do:
Move some projects from Jira cloud based server instance to locally host server.

Our projects are not big, and there are not any plugins used.
There are some custom stuff done, but not much at all.

Have anybody tried it, during the recent months? 
experiences about risks? failures? success?

thanks for all feedback

Answer (score 0):

> Our projects are not big, and there are not any plugins used. There are some custom stuff done, but not much at all.

^^ That already helps to remove much of the risk. If your locally hosted server is on the latest available version of jira, then that also reduces the risk of any problems.

Atlassian's [documentation about migrating from cloud to jira server](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver/migrating-from-jira-cloud-to-server-applications-938846963.html) is pretty decent. It's always best to try it out with a test instance first, before you plan your production migration, so in case you do run into a problem, it shouldn't do much harm. Atlassian support is also pretty responsive, so you can always check with them if needed.

I've done several migrations in either direction and the complexity always comes from:
- add-ons
- custom scripting to enhance jira's behaviour or integrate with other applications
- migrations in combinations with upgrades

Since you don't have any of those, your migration should be swift and easy.

Comment: Perfect, sounds good.
It would be really awful if we loose any data on this. Good to hear that you have positive experience.